# ASP.NET Application Understanding

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I am trying to learn the details of ASP.NET Application and bit confused about my understanding on some topics; please clarify if you think I am wrong somewhere.

1. An Application domain is created when a first request is received at the web server.
2. Multiple Application Domains are created for simultaneous request when existing Application domains are found busy.
3. An  Application domain remains alive and reused for further request. This Application domain can shutdown due to server restart or any Modification/Update in Web application files
4. An Application pool can hold anywhere from 1 to 100 Application domains.

Comment: I have got the votes but no YES/NO in support of my question. Is my understanding correct or the points mentioned above are not correct